# MongoDb two collections or one?

Tags: mongodb

I am beginner in Mongodb.

I have a products collection with details:

```
products:[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "CocaCola",
      discount: true
    }
]
```

Some products may have a discount. For that I decided to add property:

```
{ discount: true }
```

Should I create a separated `discounts_products` collection to store details of discount or better includ all information directly in product.discount?

I am a bit confused after related databases.

I try to consider this step from others sides (insert ,update and reading data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to have that as a field.

Instead of a boolean flag, you can keep how much percentage discount is.

### If it is boolean

You can check for `$exists` on `discount` field to find discounted field.

### If it is a number

You can use `$gte, $lte` to find products with more or less than particular discount.

### About non discount products

It is not mandatory that all documents/rows should have that field. You can opt out that field for the product which doesn't have discount.

If you need boolean for particular use case, then you need additional field to store how much percent discount is.

## Reason to avoid separate collection:

1. There could be a use case where you need to get both discounted and non discounted products. You need to make two http requests.
2. You need to move/delete product forth and back between two collections when product goes from discounted to non discounted.

In cases of single collection, you can remove this field when the product becomes non discounted or you can set as false if you keep boolean or you can set as 0 if you plan to keep a number.

If it is a complex object, you can have a nested object like

```
 {
   _id:12,
  product_name : "phone", 
  discount: {
   startTime:time, 
   .... OtherFields
  } 
 }
```

Comment: What if field discount complecated? With startTime, endTime, conditions?

Comment: And then I need to make request with where startTime < time() and valueDiscount > 35

Comment: How much it effects on performance, when I just need to get maximum discount from among all products? In your case MongoDb gets all products and then aggregate data to calculate the maximal discount. So, what if products collection over 5GB, how much it is more performed aomparing separated collection DoscountCollections, that stores only idPorduct and doscount value and  weighs not more 200mb?

Comment: If you have index, it will be pretty quick. 5gb is small amount of data from mongodb perspective. Again I would suggest you to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb is designed to get rid of the relational data, use that to get the benefit from this pattern and the high performance that you would expect.

So my answer will be to add the discounts to the property in products.

By inserting you could maybe insert it with the value null when that is the default behaviour, otherwise just add the amount of discount or whatever you have to add to it, updating and reading date will be the same (checking if not null).